# What log shows (last data in the string)

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.8 (I am aware this is an old release, but I am following a textbook).

Django log shows something like this:

```
[29/Jul/2016 17:22:50]"GET /tag/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1389
[29/Jul/2016 17:22:52]"GET /tag/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1389
[29/Jul/2016 17:23:03]"GET /tag/video-games/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1258
[29/Jul/2016 17:23:10]"GET /tag/mobile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1248
[29/Jul/2016 17:23:12]"GET /tag/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1389
```

The settings are default, I have not changed the logging configuration.

We can see URI here, protocol, status code.

Well, I can't decipher the last column here (with 1389, 1258, 1248). What do these signify?

Comment: It's the resource content length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of the response in bytes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13167713)

Comment: How it doesn't answer the question? Question asked what is the last column in log, and it's the size of the response in bytes.